# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Tags: android, retrofit

I´m trying to use retrofit to get data from a laravel web page I have developed, but I don´t know why I keep getting this message.
Here`s my API:

```
public class API {

    public static final String BASE_URL="http://tfg.test/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApi(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

I have read some solutions saying that I should onclude "http://" or "https://" in my base_url but it is already that way and still doesn´t work.

Comment: You are using `baseUrl("BASE_URL")`, but it should be `baseUrl(BASE_URL)`.

Comment: @S. Gomez post it as an answer. It's the correct one